# PayPal gateway rejected the request. Field format error: 10431-Item amount is invalid

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout, magento-1.8

I am using `Magento 1.8.0.0` version with `Paypal Website Payments Pro Payflow` Edition (Includes Express Checkout) Payment Methods for my website.

I have used `shopping cart price rule` to give some discounts to customers.
But whenever discount is applied , the payment methods will not recognized orders.
It seems the below error message.

```
PayPal gateway rejected the request. Field format error: 10431-Item amount is invalid
```

But the payment gateway works fine without `shopping cart price rules`.

How do I fix this issue?

Any help much appreciation!.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a price rounding issue. The Magento might has calculated the price as more than two digits after period while Paypal considers just two. Example Magento resulted the price as $24.449 while Paypal just considers it $24.44.